# Shebangs do not like sudo in OSX

Tags: linux, macos, sudo, osx-mavericks, shebang

Using sudo in the shebang seems completely broken. The following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash
echo "this should work"
```

works fine on Ubuntu, but on OSX gives me:

```
sudo: effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 
'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?
```

Any ideas how to get this to work?

Note: sudo works just fine otherwise:

```
/usr/bin/sudo echo "This works"
Password:
This works
```

Comment: Why would you use `sudo` in a shebang line?

Comment: It's a ruby script that needs to modify system files. It's for personal use, so I don't care about others abusing the facility, but I don't want to have to type `sudo command_name` every time. Or, more to the point, I don't want to forget to type sudo and have to type `sudo !!`. tldr; I'm lazy :)

Comment: You could consider using shell aliases or functions to wrap the command you want to execute.

Comment: Depending on how long your system is set before it expires the root shell, you could instead just use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and on the following line `sudo -i` or `su -`.  In either case, you will be prompted for your password, and then it should be able to enter and exit the root shell throughout your script execution.  Use `sudo -k` at the end to expire the timestamp and logout. Or, if this is something that could be a `cronjob`, just schedule it from the root crontab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that when the OS X kernel launches an interpreter via a shebang line, it doesn't check for the setuid bit on the interpreter executable. Probably should be considered a bug, although it's possible it's considered a security measure... but if so it's not a very useful one, because there's a fairly simple workaround:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/sudo /bin/bash
echo "running as $USER"
```

...this makes the kernel pass the script to /usr/bin/env (without checking for setuid, but it doesn't matter here), which passes it to /usr/bin/sudo (via the normal launch process, which *does* obey the setuid flag), which switches to root and passes the script to /bin/bash.

(BTW, `#!/usr/bin/env /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/ruby` works as well.)

Comment: Hah - excellent answer! I thought the shebang would fail with that many params to `env`. On OSX, `sudo` and `ruby` can be written without /usr/bin, though for some reason, bizarrely, Ubuntu needs the `/usr/bin` on ruby. This leaves me with a problem, as my ruby is in `~/.rbenv/stubs/ruby` - maybe I should symlink it and be done! Thanks though, you've got me much closer to a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a workaround, though I would love to know if there's a better way to do this.

The original use was for a ruby script - I found out that ruby allows you to do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "sudo-running ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
sudo ruby "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
exit $?

#!ruby
puts "It works! File is #{__FILE__}"
```

Of course, this only works in ruby :)